# Is there any SEO impacts on unattached vs attached images for a post in WordPress?

Tags: posts, images, seo

I usually bulk upload images to the WordPress Media Library and then add them add them in post, it remains unattached.

Is there any specific SEO impacts on unattached vs attached images for a post?

Thanks.

Comment: That will obviously depend on the SEO plugin you use.

Answer (score 1):

No, there shouldn't be, but you may have other issues related to functionality in WordPress if plugins make assumption. SEO concerns the frontend output of your site, the internal data structure isn't directly relevant as Google doesn't look inside your database